# Xamarin Forms IOS build fail with Unexpected error

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Anyone experiencing this or know how to resolve this?

I have an Xamarin forms project. I can build and run in the iPhoneSimulator, but when I try to do a release build I get:
 **error : Unexpected error , System.NullReferenceException:**

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and building using MacInTheCloud remotely

See log output below after turning on Diagnostic log level:

```
Detected signing identity:
2>    Code Signing Key: "XXXXXXXXXXX" (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
2>    Provisioning Profile: "InfogenDevProfile" (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
2>    Bundle Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2>    App Id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(747,3): error : Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
2>  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
2>    at MonoTouch.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoTouch.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, MonoTouch.Tuner.MonoTouchLinkContext& context, System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition]& assemblies) [0x00145] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Tuning.cs:94 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.LinkAssemblies (System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition]& assemblies, System.String output_dir, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[T] sharedCodeTargets) [0x0029a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.cs:491 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.ManagedLink () [0x005c5] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.cs:614 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Target.ProcessAssemblies () [0x000bb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Target.cs:800 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.ProcessAssemblies () [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.cs:1396 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.BuildManaged () [0x00001] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.cs:827 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application+<>c.<BuildAll>b__134_1 (Xamarin.Bundler.Application v) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.cs:775 
2>    at System.Collections.Generic.List'1[T].ForEach (System.Action'1[T] action) [0x00024] in <c9f8153c41de4f8cbafd0e32f9bf6b28>:0 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Application.BuildAll () [0x00050] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/Application.cs:775 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Driver.Main2 (System.String[] args) [0x00481] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/mtouch.cs:1420 
2>    at Xamarin.Bundler.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4991/bf350ba5/source/xamarin-macios/tools/mtouch/mtouch.cs:945
```

Comment: I think this advice in the log: 'Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com' is the most effective way to get help/get this solved.

Comment: For anyone who has this issue.  The issue was caused by the Xamrin.Auth package 1.5.x.  I resolved it by downgrading to version 1.3.x